# Getting the values from this specific JSON

Tags: c#, .net, json

I'm trying to get all of the "last" values from this JSON here:

```
{"btc":{
  "usd": {
    "bitfinex": {
      "last": "1191.60",
      "volume": "1.99324e+7"
    },
    "bitstamp": {
      "last": "1193.06",
      "volume": "8.73693e+6"
    },
    "btce": {
      "last": "1174.27",
      "volume": "6.03521e+6"
    }
  }
}
```

But for some reason I can only access "btc" and "usd". I can't get anything out of it including the "last" values. Here is the code i'm using:

```
 private string GetPrice()
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        var data = wc.DownloadString("http://preev.com/pulse/units:btc+usd/sources:bitfinex+bitstamp+btce");
        JObject o = JObject.Parse(data);
        string response = o["btc"].ToString();
        return response;
    }
```

If I change it to:

```
o["last"].ToString();
```

It just doesn't return anything. Can someone please provide me with a solution? I also tried making a key/value dict out of it and looping over each pair. Did not work.

Comment: If you really want to use JObject, `o["btc"]["usd"]["bitfinex"]["last"]`

Comment: @stuartd what would you prefer over JObject? Worked btw.

Comment: If you were to deserialize it as a dynamic object - `dynamic o = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);` then you can address it as `o.btc.usd.bitfinex.last`

Answer (score 1):

The JObject structure is similar to a class with properties, so the first-level indexer ["btc"] returns another object that you have to query for its own properties ["usd"]

You can also opt for using [JObject.SelectToken](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm), generally not a bad idea. Other answers have shown how to chain the indexers but that's hard to read and maintain. Instead you can do:

```
jObj.SelectToken("btc[0].usd[0].bitstamp[0].last").ToString();
```

Further you can use the power of this syntax for other queries:

```
// a list o all the 'last' values
jObj.SelectTokens("btc.usd.*.last").Select(t=>t.ToString()).ToList();
```

Another advantage, if you're building a more complex system, is that you could put the queries in a config file or attributes etc to make them more manageable or deploy logic changes without rebuilding.

Yet another approach would be to build your own class structure and deserialize your json into it, so you have strongly typed values (double instead of string for the values for example)

```
public class btc {
  public usd usd {get;set;}
}
public class usd....

var btcLoaded = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<btc>(jsonString);
var lastBitstamp = btc.usd.bitstamp.last;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use: `o["btc"]["usd"]["bitfinex"]["last"].ToString()` to get the 'last' value of 'bitfinex'.

Answer (score 0):

After parsing the JSON whenever you index the `o` variable you are indexing from the root of the JSON. In order to access nested properties like 'last' you will need to index into the next level of the JSON as such:

```
var bitfinex = o["btc"]["usd"]["bitfinex"]["last"].ToString();
var bitstamp = o["btc"]["usd"]["bitstamp"]["last"].ToString();
var btce = o["btc"]["usd"]["btce"]["last"].ToString();
```

To reduce the repetition you could iterate over the properties under the `btc.usd` field.

Answer (score 0):

if u want to all last values use this..

```
decimal[] lastValues = obj.SelectTokens("$..last").ToArray()
.Select(a => a.Parent.ToObject<decimal>()).ToArray();
```

if u want to dictionary, use this..

```
var dictionary = obj["btc"]["usd"].Select(a =>
        new
        {
            Key = ((JProperty)a).Name,
            Value = a.First["last"].ToObject<decimal>()
        })
        .ToDictionary(a => a.Key, a => a.Value);
```

Comment: ToArray twice is not needed